# XAML: RelativePanel dose not fill the ListviewItem control

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a problem with a listview.Itemtemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5">
         <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="nameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="28"/>
         <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="IDtxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="ID: " FontSize="12" RelativePanel.Below="nameTxt" FontWeight="Bold"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="IDCode" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IDCode}" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.RightOf="IDtxt" RelativePanel.Below="nameTxt"/>
         <TextBlock x:Name="Stato" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Stato: " FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
      </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have to align the last textBlock `<TextBlock x:Name="Stato"/>` to the right edge of the listview but the RelativePanel seems to end at the end of the content and not fill the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `Grid` is actually not filling the `ItemTemplate` either in this case. You will need to force the ItemContainer to stretch its contents horizontally and vertically like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
   </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```